# Regular expressions moving substrings in front of specific character

Tags: python, regex, string

Hi I am trying to move the apostrophes in this string using regular expressions if possible.

string  = " R8  R16  R8  E'4  G'4.  G16  R8.  C2  R16  A4  D4  R2  D'16  B8  R16  C4  R8.  E'8  C8  C'16  C'4 "

so the output would be like this

" R8  R16  R8  E4'  G4.'  G16  R8.  C2  R16  A4  D4  R2  D16'  B8  R16  C4  R8.  E8'  C8  C16'  C4' "

Comment: Have you try anything so far?

Comment: I used this code from the answer given                   re.sub(r"'(\S+)", r"\1'", " R8 R16 R8 E'4 G'4. G16 R8. C2 R16 A4 D4 R2 D'16 B8 R16 C4 R8. E'8 C8 C'16 C'4 ")
" R8 R16 R8 E4' G4.' G16 R8. C2 R16 A4 D4 R2 D16' B8 R16 C4 R8. E8' C8 C16' C4' "                                                                                                                        but now im trying to alter it for situations with more than one apostrophe for instance  " A''4  b'2  C''4 "

Comment: Im thinking about using | operator because I only need it to go up to two apostrophes. @kinetic

Comment: I got it i just ran code a second time a loop would probably be more efficient @kinetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this as "Replace an apostrophe followed by one or more non-space characters with those non-space characters and then the apostrophe."

```
>>> re.sub(r"'(\S+)", r"\1'", " R8 R16 R8 E'4 G'4. G16 R8. C2 R16 A4 D4 R2 D'16 B8 R16 C4 R8. E'8 C8 C'16 C'4 ")
" R8 R16 R8 E4' G4.' G16 R8. C2 R16 A4 D4 R2 D16' B8 R16 C4 R8. E8' C8 C16' C4' "
```